# Jquery .change not updating field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form with 16 checkboxes. I'm trying to track the quantity of boxes checked and provide immediate feedback below the form, but I can't get the numSelected variable to update on change.

Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// the jQuery.iCheck library wraps the input in a div for styling   
$('input').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-red'
});

// count the checkboxes
var cb = $(":checkbox"),
    numSelected = 0,
    numLeft = 2 - parseInt(numSelected, 10);
$(cb).change(function () {
    //alert("a checkbox was checked!");
    var $this = $(this);         
    var numSelected = $this(':checked').length;
    $('#status-box').html("Out of "+$this.length+" images you have selected "+numSelected+" for processing, you have "+numLeft+" remaining");
});
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bxv62/) I put together, any help is appreciated!

Comment: why are you not using the events of iCheck - if you already included it? `ifChecked` or `ifUnchecked` could help you out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the plugin's provided [callbacks API](https://github.com/damirfoy/iCheck#callbacks). So basically using the `ifToggled` callback:

```
var $cb = $('input:checkbox');
$cb.iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-red'
}).on('ifToggled', function() {
    var numSelected = $cb.filter(':checked').length,
        numLeft = 2 - numSelected;
    $('#status-box').html("Out of "+$cb.length+" images you have selected "+numSelected+" for processing, you have "+numLeft+" remaining");
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bxv62/3/)

Not sure whether the negative remaining number was intended, but as that seems off-topic I'll leave the business logic bit up to you. `=]`

Comment: Well, re-reading the original code it seems like `numLeft` should be static. Well nevertheless, the logic is up to OP.

Comment: Nicely done Fabricio! I never thought to look at the iCheck plugin for an answer. FYI, I have much more logic to add, but I didn't want to clutter the question. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.image-checkbox').change(function() {
    var numSelected = $("input:checkbox:checked").length;
    alert(numSelected);
});
```

Comment: This did not work for me with the iCheck plugin active, Fabricio's answer is the correct one.